# Count the number of skew orthogonal matrices over a prime field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

Problem: count the $2 \times 2$ matrices $A$ with $A^tA=-I$ in $Z_p$ for a fixed $p>2$

Answer: If $p$ is an odd prime, the number of such matrices $A$ is twice the number of solutions $(x,y)$ to the congruence $x^2 + y^2 \equiv -1(mod p)$. Hence, for odd primes $p$, the number of such matrices $A$ is $2(p-1)$ or $2(p+1)$, according as $p \equiv 1(mod 4)$ or $p \equiv -1(mod 4)$.

Someone please clarify how it come up with $2(p-1)$ and $2(p+1)$ or show a detailed proof of this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This depends on whether $x^2+y^2$ factors (so it's like $xy$) or not.

Comment: What if it does not factors?

Comment: This user and their various incarnations (Terrence Bill etc) have repeatedly asked essentially the same question close to a dozen times now. They have never shared any original thoughts. They show no signs of learning the site rules, and continue to create new accounts to circumvent the earlier question bans/suspensions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the curve $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ defined by the equation $X^2+Y^2=-Z^2$.  We wish to count the number of points $[X,Y,Z]$ on this curve over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with $Z\neq 0$ (since those are the same as solutions to $x^2+y^2=-1$, taking $x=X/Z$ and $y=Y/Z$).  We will count this by counting all the points on $C$ and then subtracting the points with $Z=0$.

First, let us show that $C$ has at least one point.  If there are no two squares whose sum is $-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then $a\mapsto -1-a$ would be an injection from the set of squares to the set of nonsquares.  But there are $\frac{p+1}{2}$ squares and only $\frac{p-1}{2}$ nonsquares, so this is impossible.

So, $C$ has a point over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.  Since $C$ is a conic (and is smooth since $p>2$), projection from that point gives an isomorphism $C\cong\mathbb{P}^1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, so $C$ has $p+1$ points over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Now we count the points of $C$ with $Z=0$.  These are solutions in $\mathbb{P}^1$ to $X^2+Y^2=0$.  Equivalently, these are solutions to $x^2=-1$ where $x=X/Y$.  If $p$ is $1$ mod $4$ then $-1$ is a square mod $p$ so there are two solutions, and if $p$ is $-1$ mod $4$ then $-1$ is not a square so there are no solutions.

So, if $p$ is $1$ mod $4$, there are $(p+1)-2=p-1$ solutions to $x^2+y^2=-1$.  If $p$ is $-1$ mod $4$, there are instead $(p+1)-0=p+1$ solutions.